# How can I position text to the side on an image (in a comment) in Excel, using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm adding images to a comment in Excel using the following:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").AddComment

With Range("A1").Comment.Shape
    .Fill.UserPicture "C:\Temp\110003.jpg"
    .Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    .Height = 200
    .Width = 200
End With
```

I then wanted to add some text to the comment as well:

```
Range("A1").Comment.Text "Text over the top of the image"
Range("A1").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
```

This places the text over the image.  Is there any way that I can place the text to the right of the image, alongside it so that it isn't over the top of the image?